# MVC Controller returning JSON to populate Select list but value needs to have a colon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC Controller that returns JSON which is what we want.
We then populate a Select list with options that the values have a colon in them.
JSON:
{result: {["ValueOne": "Option 1: My Option", "ValueTwo" : "Option 2: Other Option"]}

We are populating the list with jQuery from a $.ajax

```
 $("#EventNameDropdownList").change(function () {
                   GetEventDatesAndTimes();
               })

           function GetEventDatesAndTimes() {
               var eventName = $('#EventNameDropdownList').val();// On get from EventNameDropdownList the value is coming back as "Option 1:" instead of the whole value.

               var url = '@Url.Action("GetEventDateTimeByName", "Product")';
               $("#EventIdAndDateDropdownList").find('option').remove().end(); // clear before appending new list
               $.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: "GET",
                   cache: false,
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: { eventName: eventName },
                   success: function (data) {
                       console.log("Success");
                       if (data.eventDateTimeList.length) {
                           $.each(data.eventDateTimeList, function (i, event) {
                               console.log("ForEach: " + event.EventName);
                               $("#EventIdAndDateDropdownList").append("<option value=" + event.StartDateTime + ">" + event.StartDateTime + "</option>")
                           });
                       } else {
                           $("#EventIdAndDateDropdownList").find('option').remove().end(); // clear before appending new list

                           console.log("result NO data");

                       }

                   },
                   error: function () {
                       $("#EventIdAndDateDropdownList").find('option').remove().end(); // clear list
                       alert("An error occurred getting the Event Names");
                   }
               });
           }
```

Which is working to populate the option list fine.

Example I WANT to happen:

```
<select>
  <option value="Option 1: My Option">Option 1: My Option</option>
  <option value="Option 2: My Option">Option 2: Other Option</option>
</select>
```

But what actually comes out

```
<select>
  <option value="Option 1:" My Option>Option 1: My Option</option>
  <option value="Option 2:" My Option>Option 2: Other Option</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in the Option value property the string terminates after the colon, so the whole value from the JSON string with the colon does not get surrounded by the quotes.

Comment: You can escape the colon before sending it to the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate using `'` like

```
'<option value="' + event.StartDateTime + '">' + event.StartDateTime + '</option>'
```

Comment: Always the easy answers when you have been looking at it too long.  Thanks, that was exactly it.  String building issue.

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide the javascript that is actually creating the DOM elements?  I imagine you are inserting the the values from the JSON and then inserting that into the DOM, something like:

```
options.each(function(){
   var option = "<option " + this + ">" + this + "</option>";
   // append the option into select
})
```

Update:
@ClosDesign has the correct answer.

Comment: Updated question with jQuery. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Can you do me a favor, if you do typeof event.StartDateTime, what do you get? I'm guessing it's not a string.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to StackOverflow so I'm learning the paradigm here, and also earning privileges. I actually just now unlocked the ability to leave comments (50 rep), so next time I'll do that. Thanks again.